# excel filter columns by strings

Tags: excel, filter

I have a excel sheet with 1800 rows and 30 columns. I only need around 7 columns which never change in name (for example: "Name" "Last name" "Title" etc).

Is there a possibility to set a filter to do this? I only found a filter with 2 criteria while I need 7.

Is there an addon/script available or do I need to write one on my own? (never programed in excel)

Google results differed from my problem. (maybe I overlooked something)

/edit:

more information:
the files have this format example:
"Name", "Title" , "x" , "y" ,"important1","important2", "x"

and the next:
"Name", "Title", "important1", "x","important2","x","y"

I've changed Tony's code to the following:

```
Option Explicit
Sub DeleteOtherColumnsBeta()

Dim ColCrnt As Long
Dim ColsToKeepNum() As Long
Dim ColsToKeepName() As Variant
Dim InxKeep As Long

' Load names of columns that are to remain visible.  The code below assumes
' these names are in ascending order by column number.  These names must be
' exactly the same as in the worksheet: same case, same spaces, etc.
ColsToKeepName = Array(
"Teilbereich", "Anrede", "Titel", "Vorname", "Nachname", "Lehrveranstaltung", _
"Lehrveranstaltungsart", "Periode", "Bogen")

ReDim ColsToKeepNum(LBound(ColsToKeepName) To UBound(ColsToKeepName))


With Sheets("Sheet1")     ' Replace "Sheet3" with the name of your sheet

' Locate columns to remain visible
ColCrnt = 1
For InxKeep = LBound(ColsToKeepName) To UBound(ColsToKeepName)
  Do While ColsToKeepName(InxKeep) <> .Cells(1, ColCrnt).Value
    ColCrnt = ColCrnt + 1
    If ColCrnt > Columns.Count Then
      Call MsgBox("Column headed """ & ColsToKeepName(InxKeep) & _
                                                 """ not found", vbOKOnly)
      Exit Sub
    End If
  Loop
  ColsToKeepNum(InxKeep) = ColCrnt
  Call MsgBox("ColsToKeepNum(InxKeep)""" & ColsToKeepNum(InxKeep), vbOKOnly)
Next

' ColsToKeepNum() now contains a list of column numbers which are
' the columns to remain visible.  All others are to be hidden.

ColCrnt = Columns.Count ' Last column processed
' Hide columns before first named column and between named columns
For InxKeep = UBound(ColsToKeepName) To LBound(ColsToKeepName)
  If ColCrnt - 1 = ColsToKeepNum(InxKeep) Then
    ' There is no gap between last processed column and this column
    ' containing columns to be hidden
  Else
    .Range(.Cells(1, ColCrnt - 1), _
           .Cells(1, ColsToKeepNum(InxKeep) + 1)).EntireColumn.Delete
  End If
  ColCrnt = ColsToKeepNum(InxKeep)      ' Last processed column
Next
'Hide columns after last named column
.Range(.Cells(1, ColCrnt - 1), _
           .Cells(1, Columns.Count)).EntireColumn.Delete

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You can sort by multiple criteria. What version of excel? Also your question isn't very clear, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Use a pivot table.  In 2007 or 2010 hit the insert ribbon, pivottable.

Comment: Do you want to hide particular columns, or remove them? Tony's answer does seem to automate hiding them. Or would you prefer they not be in your sheet?

Comment: 1. i use excel 2010
2. i would prefer them to be deleted/not in my sheet anymore

thanks for your comments. will try to clarify my questions in the future.

Comment: 3. @Jesse: Maybe i am to dumb but the report layout isnt the goal i had in mind. (gonna check all options if i can get it to the normal layout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter is just an easy way for the user to hide rows or columns.  I believe the code below offers a suitable alternative in your situation.

Replace the names in:

```
ColsToKeepName = Array("Name", "Addr", "Title", "Given", "Phone", _
                       "Home", "Mobile")
```

with the names of the columns you wish to remain visible.  You can increase or decrease the number of names.  The names must be in ascending order by column number and must match the column headers in the worksheet exactly.

Macro `HideOtherColumns` will hide all the other columns

Macro `RestoreColumns` will restore the hidden columns.

I think the code is fairly simple so the comments only explain the purpose of the code.  Come back with questions if you do not understand what I am doing.

Hope this helps.

```
Option Explicit
Sub HideOtherColumns()

  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim ColsToKeepNum() As Long
  Dim ColsToKeepName() As Variant
  Dim InxKeep As Long

  ' Load names of columns that are to remain visible.  The code below assumes
  ' these names are in ascending order by column number.  These names must be
  ' exactly the same as in the worksheet: same case, same spaces, etc.
  ColsToKeepName = Array("Name", "Addr", "Title", "Given", "Phone", _
                         "Home", "Mobile")

  ReDim ColsToKeepNum(LBound(ColsToKeepName) To UBound(ColsToKeepName))

  With Sheets("Sheet3")     ' Replace "Sheet3" with the name of your sheet 

    ' Locate columns to remain visible
    ColCrnt = 1
    For InxKeep = LBound(ColsToKeepName) To UBound(ColsToKeepName)
      Do While ColsToKeepName(InxKeep) <> .Cells(1, ColCrnt).Value
        ColCrnt = ColCrnt + 1
        If ColCrnt > Columns.Count Then
          Call MsgBox("Column headed """ & ColsToKeepName(InxKeep) & _
                                                     """ not found", vbOKOnly)
          Exit Sub
        End If
      Loop
      ColsToKeepNum(InxKeep) = ColCrnt
    Next

    ' ColsToKeepNum() now contains a list of column numbers which are
    ' the columns to remain visible.  All others are to be hidden.

    ColCrnt = 0     ' Last column processed
    ' Hide columns before first named column and between named columns
    For InxKeep = LBound(ColsToKeepName) To UBound(ColsToKeepName)
      If ColCrnt + 1 = ColsToKeepNum(InxKeep) Then
        ' There is no gap between last processed column and this column
        ' containing columns to be hidden
      Else
        .Range(.Cells(1, ColCrnt + 1), _
               .Cells(1, ColsToKeepNum(InxKeep) - 1)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
      End If
      ColCrnt = ColsToKeepNum(InxKeep)      ' Last processed column
    Next
    'Hide columns after last named column
    .Range(.Cells(1, ColCrnt + 1), _
               .Cells(1, Columns.Count)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True

  End With

End Sub
Sub RestoreColumns()

  With Sheets("Sheet3")
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, Columns.Count)).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
  End With

End Sub
```

**New routine to delete columns from all xls files in same folder as master workbook**

Remember: once a column is deleted it cannot be recovered.  So make sure you have a copy of the original files.  However, the code here does not delete anything.  Instead it outputs a description of what ought to be deleted.  I have tested this code but we need to check it with your workbooks before deleting columns.

I am going to call the workbook containing the macros `Master.xls`.  This code assumes all the workbooks from which columns are to be deleted are in the same folder as `Master.xls`.  This code assumes `Master.xls` contains a worksheet named `DelCol`.  Change `DelCol` within the code if you do not like my choice of names.

You are going to need a routine that finds all the Excel files in a folder.  I wrote this one earlier:

```
Sub GetFileNameList(ByVal PathCrnt As String, ByVal FileSpec As String, _
                                            ByRef FileNameList() As String)

' This routine sets FileNameList to the names of files within folder
' PathCrnt that match FileSpec.  It uses function Dir$() to get the file names.
' I can find no documentation that says Dir$() gets file names in alphabetic
' order but I have not seen a different sequence in recent years

  Dim AttCrnt As Long
  Dim FileNameCrnt As String
  Dim InxFNLCrnt As Long

  ReDim FileNameList(1 To 100)
  InxFNLCrnt = 0

  ' Ensure path name ends in a "\"
  If Right(PathCrnt, 1) <> "\" Then
    PathCrnt = PathCrnt & "\"
  End If

  ' This Dir$ returns the name of the first file in
  ' folder PathCrnt that matches FileSpec.
  FileNameCrnt = Dir$(PathCrnt & FileSpec)
  Do While FileNameCrnt <> ""
    ' "Files" have attributes, for example: normal, to-be-archived, system,
    ' hidden, directory and label. It is unlikely that any directory will
    ' have an extension of XLS but it is not forbidden.  More importantly,
    ' if the files have more than one extension so you have to use "*.*"
    ' instead of *.xls", Dir$ will return the names of directories. Labels
    ' can only appear in route directories and I have not bothered to test
    ' for them
    AttCrnt = GetAttr(PathCrnt & FileNameCrnt)
    If (AttCrnt And vbDirectory) <> 0 Then
      ' This "file" is a directory.  Ignore
    Else
      ' This "file" is a file
      InxFNLCrnt = InxFNLCrnt + 1
      If InxFNLCrnt > UBound(FileNameList) Then
        ' There is a lot of system activity behind "Redim Preserve".  I reduce
        ' the number of Redim Preserves by adding new entries in chunks and
        ' using InxFNLCrnt to identify the next free entry.
        ReDim Preserve FileNameList(1 To 100 + UBound(FileNameList))
      End If
      FileNameList(InxFNLCrnt) = FileNameCrnt
    End If
    ' This Dir$ returns the name of the next file that matches
    ' the criteria specified in the initial call.
    FileNameCrnt = Dir$
  Loop

  ' Discard the unused entries
  ReDim Preserve FileNameList(1 To InxFNLCrnt)

End Sub
```

Despite its name the macro below does not delete columns.  It does everything necessary except delete columns.  The macro checks every worksheet or every workbook in the folder.  If a worksheet does not contain all required columns, the macro reports it.  If a worksheet does contain all required columns, it reports which columns are to be deleted.

Test this macro on your system and check that it is working to your satisfaction.  By then I will have tested the delete code.

```
Sub DeleteColumns()

  Dim ColOtherCrnt As Long
  Dim ColOtherEnd As Long
  Dim ColOtherStart As Long
  Dim ColOtherMax As Long
  Dim ColsToDelete() As Long
  Dim ColsToKeepFound() As Boolean
  Dim ColsToKeepName() As Variant
  Dim FileNameList() As String
  Dim Found As Boolean
  Dim InxCTDCrnt As Long
  Dim InxCTDMax As Long
  Dim InxCTK As Long
  Dim InxFNLCrnt As Long
  Dim InxWShtCrnt As Long
  Dim Msg As String
  Dim PathCrnt As String
  Dim RowDelColNext As Long
  Dim WBookMaster As Workbook
  Dim WBookOther As Workbook

  If Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
    ' It is easy to get into a muddle if there are multiple workbooks
    ' open at the start of a macro like this.  Avoid the problem.
    Call MsgBox("Please close all other workbooks", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Set WBookMaster = ActiveWorkbook

  ' Load names of columns that are NOT to be deleted  These names must be
  ' actually the same as in the worksheet: same case, same spaces, etc.
  ' ##### Change this list as required. #####
  ColsToKeepName = Array("Name", "Addr", "Title", "Given", "Phone", "Home", "Mobile")

  ' Get the name of the folder containing this workbook.
  PathCrnt = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

  ' Delete existing contents of worksheet DelCol and prepare for use
  With Sheets("DelCol")
    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete
    .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Workbook"
    .Cells(1, 2).Value = "Worksheet"
    .Cells(1, 3).Value = "Comment"
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 3)).Font.Bold = True
  End With
  RowDelColNext = 2

  ' If you are using a later version of Excel, you will
  ' need to change the file specification.
  Call GetFileNameList(PathCrnt, "*.xls", FileNameList)

  For InxFNLCrnt = 1 To UBound(FileNameList)
    If FileNameList(InxFNLCrnt) = WBookMaster.Name Then
      ' This workbook is the master
      Set WBookOther = WBookMaster
    Else
      Set WBookOther = Workbooks.Open(PathCrnt & FileNameList(InxFNLCrnt))
    End If
    With WBookOther
      ' Store name of workbook
      WBookMaster.Sheets("DelCol").Cells(RowDelColNext, 1).Value = .Name
      RowDelColNext = RowDelColNext + 1

      ' Examine every worksheet in workbook
      For InxWShtCrnt = 1 To .Worksheets.Count
        With .Worksheets(InxWShtCrnt)
          ' Store name of worksheet
          WBookMaster.Sheets("DelCol").Cells(RowDelColNext, 2).Value = .Name
          RowDelColNext = RowDelColNext + 1

          ' #### Add code to ignore any workbooks
          ' #### you do not want examined

          ' .Range(Y).SpecialCells(X) finds a cell or cells of type X
          ' within range Y.  ".Cells" means the entire worksheet.
          ' "xlCellTypeLastCell" means the last used cell or cells.
          ' I have extracted the column number.  If ColOtherMax = 50
          ' then I know I need not consider columns 51, 52, etc.
          ColOtherMax = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

          ' Size array for one entry per name.  Initialise to False
          ReDim ColsToKeepFound(LBound(ColsToKeepName) To _
                                UBound(ColsToKeepName))

          ' Size array for the maximum possible number of columns.
          ReDim ColsToDelete(1 To ColOtherMax)
          InxCTDMax = 0       ' Array currently empty

          ' Example row 1 of every column
          For ColOtherCrnt = ColOtherMax To 1 Step -1

            ' Match column header against names to keep
            Found = False
            For InxCTK = LBound(ColsToKeepName) To UBound(ColsToKeepName)
              If .Cells(1, ColOtherCrnt).Value = ColsToKeepName(InxCTK) Then
                Found = True
                Exit For
              End If
            Next

            ' Record findings
            If Found Then
              ' This column is to be kept
              ColsToKeepFound(InxCTK) = True
            Else
              ' This column is to be deleted
              InxCTDMax = InxCTDMax + 1
              ColsToDelete(InxCTDMax) = ColOtherCrnt
            End If
          Next

          ' Check all columns to be kept have been found
          Found = True
          For InxCTK = LBound(ColsToKeepName) To UBound(ColsToKeepName)
            If Not ColsToKeepFound(InxCTK) Then
              Found = False
              Exit For
            End If
          Next

          If Found Then
            ' All required columns have been found.  Prepare to
            ' delete remaining columns
            Msg = "Columns to be deleted:"
            ColOtherStart = ColsToDelete(1)
            ColOtherEnd = ColsToDelete(1)
            For InxCTDCrnt = 2 To InxCTDMax
              If ColsToDelete(InxCTDCrnt) + 1 = ColOtherStart Then
                ' Range continues
                ColOtherStart = ColsToDelete(InxCTDCrnt)
              Else
                ' End of last range. Start of new.
                If ColOtherStart = ColOtherEnd Then
                  Msg = Msg & " " & ColOtherStart & " "
                Else
                  Msg = Msg & " " & ColOtherStart & " to " & ColOtherEnd & " "
                End If
                ColOtherStart = ColsToDelete(InxCTDCrnt)
                ColOtherEnd = ColsToDelete(InxCTDCrnt)
              End If
            Next
            If ColOtherStart = ColOtherEnd Then
              Msg = Msg & " " & ColOtherStart & " "
            Else
              Msg = Msg & " " & ColOtherStart & " to " & ColOtherEnd & " "
            End If
            WBookMaster.Sheets("DelCol").Cells(RowDelColNext, 2).Value = Msg
            RowDelColNext = RowDelColNext + 1
          Else
            ' Not all required columns found.
            Msg = "The following required columns were not found:"
            For InxCTK = LBound(ColsToKeepName) To UBound(ColsToKeepName)
                If Not ColsToKeepFound(InxCTK) Then
                  Msg = Msg & " " & ColsToKeepName(InxCTK)
              End If
            Next
            WBookMaster.Sheets("DelCol").Cells(RowDelColNext, 3).Value = Msg
            RowDelColNext = RowDelColNext + 1
          End If
        End With
      Next
      If FileNameList(InxFNLCrnt) = WBookMaster.Name Then
        ' This workbook is the master
      Else
        .Close SaveChanges:=False   ' Close the workbook without saving it
      End If
      Set WBookOther = Nothing    ' Clear reference to workbook
    End With
  Next

End Sub
```

**Comments on second routine**

Don't worry about using Java.  I was once fluent in C and can understand the syntax of most C derived languages.

The new code does not require the columns to be in any particular sequence because you say the sequence is not the same in all workbooks.

Both the new and the old code require an exact match.  There are many techniques that allow for partial matches but I do not know which would be appropriate.  For example:

- `if Lcase(X) = Lcase(Y) then` would mean that "NAME", "name" and "Name" all matched.
- `if Replace(X," ","") = Replace(Y," ","") then` would mean that "first name" and "firstname" matched.
- `Like` is an operator that performs wildcard matching.
- You have discovered `Instr` which is another possibility although I suspect `Like` will give you more flexibility.  However I am a little uncomfortable with `InStr` and `Like`.  They would allow you to match "addr" with "address" and "home addr" but also "name" with "enamel".  It seems unlikely that the word "enamel" appears in any of your header rows but I hope you see my concern.
- If you are using a later version of Excel than I am, you have access to Regex with all its flexibility.
- You can nest calls, for example: `Lcase(Replace(X," ",""))`.

The purpose of the new code is to test the effect of the routine without deleting anything.  If you are going to look for partial matches, I suggest you change the output to worksheet "ColDel" to include a list of the matched names.

You do not have to be able to handle every workbook in a single pass.  You could handle the easy workbooks and move them elsewhere leaving you to concentrate on the difficult ones.

Comment: thank you very much! will try this.
i understand the coding (never wrote code in excel but in java).
greetings!

Comment: works like a charm (getting excel to use this macro whenever i want was a little wicked)

Comment: You are welcome.  In one of your comments you say you would rather remove the columns from the sheet.  It is easy to delete columns if that is what you want.

Comment: i sure would like to do that. i guess its just "EntireColumn.Delete ==true". or at least something like that. i am searching for a good API for VBA since i just got an order to write an entire dynamic script ^^.
cheers.

Comment: There is no "==" in Excel.  "=" is used for assignment and equality.  Its just "EntireColumn.Delete".  Don't replace `.Hidden=True` in my code with `Delete` because I located the columns in advance.  If you just want to delete the columns why not do it from the keyboard?  Click on the "G", say, click `Edit` then `Delete` and column "G" will be deleted.

Comment: oO no ==? sad. by keyboard u mean deleting every column by hand? i got many files with the same structure thats why i didnt want to do it manually.

Comment: If you delete column 5, columns 6, 7, 8, etc, will move left so no simple variation of my code will work.  Is it the same worksheet in each workbook? Is it the same seven column names in each worksheet?  Are they in the same sequence?  My code is not designed to work on multiple workbooks.  I suggest you add a second section to your question which explains the full requirement.

Comment: well the names are the same the columns can differ. i changed your code to delete from right to left (as u mentioned otherwise the rowcount would change). however this code does not work atm. gonna add it to the original post.
i rly appreciate your help! but i dont want to take your freetime to much :)

Comment: I have added a new section to my answer.  Please install and test the new routines.

Comment: looked over your code and correct me if i am wrong but your code needs "Name", "Addr", "Title", etc in the same order right?
is there a function that analyzes the columnstring for its content?

in java you can do
`if (stringTest.contains =="ame"){}`
which would allow to search for keywords independent from lower and uppercase, spaces, etc. (example: keyword is Apple. table a has a column "This Apple is nice". table b has a column "These Apples are nice". -> resulting in both columns to be saved from deletion)

Comment: found it: InStr("Look in this string", "look") -> `For(int i=0; i< ColsToKeepName.length; i++)`
`InStr(ColOtherCrnt, ColsToKeepName[i])`
gonna build this in. (this is a mixup from vba and java only for me to get into vba)

Comment: i created an Master.xls into a testfolder with 3 testfiles.
then i renamed Sheet1 to DelCol and added 2 Modules to the Master.xls containing your codes with modified Array and Filetype (i am using .csv so i changed your filescanfunction to ".csv").
after that i tested the macro: after going through the files it ended up showing me an empty DelCol worksheet. gonna fix it now.

Comment: I have added another section to my answer with further suggestions.